# Magento Import Customer Error...Now Applicatiion itself not running?

Tags: database, magento, import, backup

My magento site which was working fine before an hour now giving error as I have **imported
customer data from csv file with REPLACE Esisting Complex Data mode** as we want to update some of our customer data.

but when I tried to add product into the cart from frontend with existing customer it gives me error as-:

```
Item (Model_Customer_Customer) with the same id "11" already exist

exception 'Exception' with message 'Item with the same id "11" already exist' in /htdocs/localhost/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php:373
```

Can somebody guide me what should I do now??

Or tell me how can I revert back to original database as I take backup of database daily.
So I have yesterday's backup of database of my site.

So how can I revert back to yesterday's database?

plz plz help me....

Comment: Yes...there is duplicate data as that of existing data...thats why I import with REplace existing data mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverting is fairly simple create a new database and call it another name so say your current db is magento1 create magento2 with your backedup data, and make sure your current magento db user has rights to the new database.

Now edit app/etc/local.xml change `<dbname><![CDATA[magento1]]></dbname>` to `<dbname><![CDATA[magento2]]></dbname>`, clear all caches and your site should now be pointing at the old data.

This is a quick fix method, but it seems like that is what you are looking for right now.

Comment: yes...does it solve my problem...As some of my custom code is not working right now with this data.

Comment: It should solve your problem. Have you made code changes as well since you have done the import? If you haven't, then just reverting back to the old db should take care of the issue.

Comment: no...after import I havn't change any code...but since then product is unable to add in cart...

Comment: So after reverting to old data you cant add to cart? What happens when you try adding to cart?

Comment: No  Gershon... I am just now trying to revert back...I just wanted to confirm whether this is right way or not...